# apacheで全てのアクセスを指定した階層下にリダイレクトしたい

Tags: apache, .htaccess

apacheにて
全てのアクセスを指定した階層下に**URLを保持したまま**リダイレクトしたいです。

下記のような感じです

```
www.example.com -> www.example.com/test
www.example.com/login -> www.example.com/test/login
```

記述としては

```
 Rewriterule ^(/.*)$ /test$1 [R=301,L]
```

だと思うのですが、これだとリダイレクトループになりますので、
RedirectCondで条件指定するのですが、
URLを保持したままリダイレクトしたいので

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test(/.*)$
```

が使えないため悩んでおります。

Comment: `N` フラグはどうでしょうか？ `RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /test$1 [N]`(`RewriteCond` はそのままで)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「URLを保持したままリダイレクト」の意味は、HTTPレスポンスの 301,302リダイレクトではなく、mod_rewrite で言うところの内部サブリクエストとか、内部リダイレクトと呼ばれるものではないでしょうか。
もし、そうれあれば、R=301 は必要なく、以下のように設定するといいと思います。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It works!
 動作しました！ありがとうございます！！
内部リダイレクトを指していたようです。勉強不足でした...